# In how many ways can I sum integers from $1$ to $N-1$ to obtain $N$?

Tags: combinatorics

I'm looking for the exact formula for $f(N) =$ number of ways to sum $1, 2, ..., N-1$ to obtain $N$.

$N$ is an integer $> 0$. Integers $1, 2, ..., N-1$ can be used $0$ or 1 time as an element in the sum.

For example:

$f(6) = 3$. There are 3 ways to obtain 6 from integers less than $6$:

$1+2+3$
$1+5$
$2+4$

Answer (score 4, accepted):

A summation of $n$ from integer summands is called a [partition](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Partition_%28number_theory%29).

The number of distinct partitions defines the partition function $p(n)$.
It includes the case $n = n$ and summands can show up more than once.
So your $f(n) < p(n)$. One of the OEIS comments calls partitions with summands not repeating "restricted partitions", see $A_9$ below.

Searching OEIS, gives: [A111133](http://oeis.org/A111133).

> A111133 Number of partitions of $n$ into at least two distinct parts.
>
> Old name: Number of sets of natural numbers less than $n$ which sum to
>   $n$.

So we have
$$
f(n) = A_{111133
}(n)
$$

> EXAMPLE
>   $a(6) = 3$ because $1+5$, $2+4$ and $1+2+3$ each sum to $6$. That is,
>   the three sets are $\{1,5\}$,$\{2,4\}$,$\{1,2,3\}$.

**Formula:**

It seems there is only a recursive function available, [A000009](http://oeis.org/A000009) with
$$
f(n) = A_9(n) - 1
$$ 
features the comment:

> For $n>1$, 
>   $$
> a(n)=\frac{1}{n} \sum_{k=1}^n b(k) \, a(n-k)
> $$
>   with $a(0)=1$, $b(n)= A_{000593}(n)$ = sum of odd divisors of $n$; cf. A000700. - Vladeta Jovovic, Jan 21 2002

Here is a link to [A000593](http://oeis.org/A000593). That is already enough informatio to come up with a piece of code. Otherwise continue to follow the references.

Or you go down the road of the [generating functions](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Generating_function), where the coefficients of a power series of $G$ give the sequence.

Comment: https://oeis.org/A000009 gives number of partitions into distinct parts, from which $1$ should be subtracted since OP wants the sum to only have numbers less than $n$.

Comment: Thank you, this looks what I need. Could you please only write the exact formula?

Comment: @AdamStelmaszczyk The formula is given in that link.

Comment: There is no nice closed-form formula, unfortunately; but there are asymptotics, generating functions, and sums of other sequences available.

Comment: @vadim123 Are you absolutely sure that closed-form formula doesn't exist? How do we know that?

Comment: @mvw I wanted to know how exact formula looks like, because I would probably need it in a proof. So, I wanted to see for example how fast is it growing, is it like for example $n^2$ or faster. If the exact formula is too complicated (but it exitsts, right? It always exists, isn't it?) I would probably need to bound it, that let's say it's between $n$ and $n^2$ (just an example).

Comment: I do not know if there is a closed form. I would have expected it to be listed in the OEIS, if well known. But see the comments for $A_9$: Asymptotics: $a(n) \sim \exp(\pi l_n / \sqrt{3}) / ( 4 \, 3^{1/4} l_n^{3/2} )$ where $l_n = (n-1/24)^ {1/2}$ (Ayoub). Here is a graph: http://oeis.org/A111133/graph I would check the literature references to get deeper into this topic.

Comment: For interested: [plot](https://graphsketch.com/?eqn1_color=1&eqn1_eqn=exp%28pi*sqrt%28x-1%2F24%29%2Fsqrt%283%29%29%2F%284*root%283%2C4%29*sqrt%28sqrt%28x-1%2F24%29%29%5E3%29+&eqn2_color=2&eqn2_eqn=x%5E2&eqn3_color=3&eqn3_eqn=&eqn4_color=4&eqn4_eqn=&eqn5_color=5&eqn5_eqn=&eqn6_color=6&eqn6_eqn=&x_min=1&x_max=100&y_min=0&y_max=10000&x_tick=1&y_tick=1&x_label_freq=5&y_label_freq=5&do_grid=0&bold_labeled_lines=0&bold_labeled_lines=1&line_width=4&image_w=850&image_h=525) showing asymptotic $a(x)$ and $x^2$. They intersect at $x \approx 44.5$.

Answer (score 3):

The power series for
$$
\prod_{k=1}^\infty\left(1+x^k\right)
$$
which is equal to
$$
\prod_{k=1}^\infty\frac1{1-x^{2k-1}}
$$
is the generating function for your number plus $1$. The beginning of the power series is
$$
\small1+x+x^2+2x^3+2x^4+3x^5+4x^6+5x^7+6x^8+8x^9+10x^{10}+12x^{11}+15x^{12}+\dots
$$